# How to filter object based on array items using javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have encountered this problem, My aim is to filter objectOfProductsById and remove all id's based on condition, for example, if objectOfProductsById doesn't contain id's from arrOfIds i want to remove data inside objectOfProductsById. How I can achieve this result using ES6 syntax?

```js
   let arrOfIds = [2233, 1235, 4455]

    let objectOfProductsById = {
        2233: {
            productName: 'simple product'
        },
        2211: {
            productName: 'simple product2'
        },

        1111: {
            productName: 'simple product2'
        },

    }

    let newObj = Object.entries(objectOfProductsById).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (!arrOfIds.includes(key)) {
            delete objectOfProductsById[key]
        }
    })

    console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like:

```js
let arrOfIds = [2233, 1235, 4455]

let objectOfProductsById = {
  2233: {
    productName: 'simple product'
  },
  2211: {
    productName: 'simple product2'
  },
  1111: {
    productName: 'simple product2'
  },
}

let newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(objectOfProductsById)
    .filter(([key]) => arrOfIds.includes(+key))
)

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand the question, but if you're trying to copy the `objectOfProductsById` that have their IDs in `arrOfIds` into `newObj`, I would do it like this:

```
let newObj = Object.entries(objectOfProductsById)
                      .filter(([key]) => {arrOfIds.includes(key)})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go for a more scalable approach, you can iterate the ids and filter out any that aren't in your object, and then map each id to an object with its corresponding object from your `objectOfProductsById`. You can then merge these into one object to get your result. This is an O(n) solution (where *n* is the size of your array of ids):

```js
const arrOfIds = [2233, 1235, 4455];
const obj = { 2233: { productName: 'simple product' }, 2211: { productName: 'simple product2' }, 1111: { productName: 'simple product2' }, }

const newObj = Object.assign({}, ...arrOfIds
  .filter(id => id in obj).map(id => ({[id]: obj[id]}))
);
console.log(newObj);
```

If you can use features beyond ES6, then you can use `Object.fromEntries()` introduced in ES10 instead of `Object.assign()`:

```js
const arrOfIds = [2233, 1235, 4455];
const obj = { 2233: { productName: 'simple product' }, 2211: { productName: 'simple product2' }, 1111: { productName: 'simple product2' }, }

const newObj = Object.fromEntries(arrOfIds
  .filter(id => id in obj).map(id => [id, obj[id]])
);
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. ForEach returns the key values ​​of the function as strings, so it does not satisfy the if condition. You should use `parseInt()` for this

```
if (!arrOfIds.includes(parseInt(key))) {
            delete objectOfProductsById[key]
        }
```

2. Since you are using a foreach function, you can only manipulate the variable with scope. at the end of the process you should print the console `objectOfProductsById`

```
    console.log(objectOfProductsById)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Ben Stephens** answer if you want to return an object, use mine if you want to return IDs.

Use Array filter methods. The **filter()** method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test (provided as a function).

Note: **filter()** does not execute the function for array elements without values. Note: **filter()** does not change the original array.

The following will return an array of strings.

```
let arrOfIds = [2233, 1235, 4455]

let objectOfProductsById = {
    2233: {
        productName: 'simple product'
    },
    2211: {
        productName: 'simple product2'
    },

    1111: {
        productName: 'simple product2'
    },
}

let newObj = Object.keys(objectOfProductsById).filter(key => {
    return arrOfIds.includes(parseInt(key))
})

console.log(newObj)
```